# Strange static_cast compilation error while compile boost spirit parser

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

To parse expressions like follow:

```
"asd {img} {ref I}sdkflsdlk {img} wmrwerml"
```

I have code like this:

```
struct CMyTag
{
    std::string tagName;
    std::string tagData;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(::CMyTag, (std::string, tagName) (std::string, tagData));

struct fillMyTag
{
    template <typename A, typename B = boost::spirit::unused_type, typename C = boost::spirit::unused_type, typename D = boost::spirit::unused_type>
    struct result { typedef void type; };


    void operator()(::CMyTag& _tag, const std::string& _name, const std::string& _type) const
    {
        _tag.tagName = _name;
        _tag.tagData = _type;
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct testTag_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<CMyTag>()>
{
    testTag_grammar() :
        testTag_grammar::base_type(data)
    {
        data = (text | imgtag | vartag | inctag | blktag | reftag) >> *data;

        imgtagraw %= '{' >> qi::lit("img") >> *(+qi::lit(' ') >> lexeme[+(char_ - '{' - '}')]) >> '}';
        imgtag = imgtagraw[op(qi::labels::_val, "img", boost::spirit::_1)];

        vartagraw %= '{' >> qi::lit("var") >> *(+qi::lit(' ') >> lexeme[+(char_ - '{' - '}')]) >> '}';
        vartag = vartagraw[op(qi::labels::_val, "var", boost::spirit::_1)];

        inctagraw %= '{' >> qi::lit("inc") >> *(+qi::lit(' ') >> lexeme[+(char_ - '{' - '}')]) >> '}';
        inctag = inctagraw[op(qi::labels::_val, "inc", boost::spirit::_1)];

        blktagraw %= '{' >> qi::lit("blank") >> *(+qi::lit(' ') >> lexeme[+(char_ - '{' - '}')]) >> '}';
        blktag = blktagraw[op(qi::labels::_val, "blk", boost::spirit::_1)];

        reftagraw %= '{' >> lexeme[("ref")] >> *(+qi::lit(' ') >> lexeme[+(char_ - '{' - '}')]) >> '}';
        reftag = reftagraw[op(qi::labels::_val, "ref", boost::spirit::_1)];

        textraw %= lexeme[+(char_ - '{' - '}')];
        text = textraw[op(qi::labels::_val, "text", boost::spirit::_1)];
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> imgtagraw, vartagraw, inctagraw, blktagraw, reftagraw, textraw;
    qi::rule<Iterator, CMyTag()> imgtag, vartag, inctag, blktag, reftag, text;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<CMyTag>()> data;

    boost::phoenix::function<fillMyTag> op;
};
```

Usage of parser:

```
testTag_grammar<std::string::iterator> l_gramar;
std::string l_test = "asd {img} {ref I}sdkflsdlk {img} wmrwerml";

std::vector<CMyTag> l_result;
bool result = qi::parse(l_test.begin(), l_test.end(), l_gramar, l_result);
```

As a result I expect to get a list of CmyTag structs, but compilation of code failed:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const std::vector<CMyTag,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'CMyTag'    d:\lib\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\spirit\home\qi\detail\assign_to.hpp   152 1   TestSpiritParser
```

When I change data rule to follow:

```
data = ((text | imgtag | vartag | inctag | blktag | reftag)[opvec(qi::labels::_val, boost::spirit::_1)]) >> *data;
```

with definition of opvec:

```
struct fillMyVec
{
    template <typename A, typename B = boost::spirit::unused_type, typename C = boost::spirit::unused_type, typename D = boost::spirit::unused_type>
    struct result { typedef void type; };


    void operator()(std::vector<CMyTag>& _tagvec, const CMyTag& _name) const
    {
        _tagvec.push_back(_name);
    }

    void operator()(std::vector<CMyTag>& _tagvec, std::vector<CMyTag>& _name) const
    {
        _tagvec.insert(_tagvec.end(), _name.begin(), _name.end());
    }
};

boost::phoenix::function<fillMyVec> opvec;
```

Code begin compile success, but as result of run I got list with only one item in it. Also before modification, when CMytag type was only std::string, I got a std::string list with correct numbers of items in it,

Now I have no idea what wrong, and what to do for fix issue

Comment: You might like to see similar grammars: [Parsing Mustache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122557/how-to-parse-mustache-with-boost-xpressive-correctly/24131286#24131286) or [nested `{}` parser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18453062/85371)

Comment: I sovle the issue when change `data = (text | imgtag | vartag | inctag | blktag | reftag) >> *data;` to `data = (text | imgtag | vartag | inctag | blktag | reftag) >> -data;`, but solution by **sehe** much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firstly, I can only assume

   ```
   data = (text | imgtag | vartag | inctag | blktag | reftag) >> *data;
   ```

   was /meant/ as 1-or-more repeats of the (...) expression. Writing it as

   ```
   data = +(text | imgtag | vartag | inctag | blktag | reftag);
   ```

   expresses the same, but allows attribute propagation to match the exposes attribute type.
2. There are a number of `lexeme[]` directives that have no purpose when not using a skipper
3. There is a suspicious manual skipping of whitespace that might be better served by using a skipper
4. Insofar as you do wish to require a mandatory space after the "tag name", consider using `operator&` operator. That way you can still use a skipper.

   Anyhow, it's possible you were looking for something like the [Qi Repository `distinct()[]` parser directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/distinct.html)
5. Even with a skipper

   ```
   *(+lit(' ') >> lexeme[+(char_ - '{' - '}')])
   ```

   doesn't make sense as `lexeme[...]` would eat any space up to closing '}' and hence the second repeat of the `*()` would never apply.

   > See also [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)
6. There is a lot of manual repetition between rules. Consider using `qi::symbols` to map the input to tag types.
7. If you do, it becomes easier to avoid semantic actions (Good Thing: [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)). Even if you didn't, you could use `qi::attr` to expose a specific value as the `type` value.
8. Consider adding debug information (see `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` in the demo below)

### The grammar simplified

I'd reduce the whole grammar to just this:

```
data = +( ('{' >> tag >> '}') | text );

tag  = lexeme[type >> &char_(" {}")] >> lexeme[*~char_("{}")];
text = attr("text")                  >> lexeme[+~char_("{}")];
```

Done! No more semantic actions, no more dozens of rules doing basically the same. No more complicated nested repeats with unclear multiplicities. `type` is a `qi::symbols` parser now, that contains the mapping of tag names:

```
type.add
    ("img",   "img")
    ("var",   "var")
    ("inc",   "inc")
    ("blank", "blk")
    ("ref",   "ref");
```

And here's a complete demo:

## DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eba1eab8516ba9e4)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;

struct CMyTag
{
    std::string tagName;
    std::string tagData;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(::CMyTag, (std::string, tagName) (std::string, tagData))

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct testTag_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<CMyTag>(), Skipper>
{
    testTag_grammar() :
        testTag_grammar::base_type(data)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        data = +( ('{' >> tag >> '}') | text );

        type.add
            ("img",   "img")
            ("var",   "var")
            ("inc",   "inc")
            ("blank", "blk")
            ("ref",   "ref");

        tag  = lexeme[type >> &char_(" {}")] >> lexeme[*~char_("{}")];
        text = attr("text")                  >> lexeme[+~char_("{}")];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( (data) (tag) (text))
    }

  private:
    qi::symbols<char, std::string> type;
    qi::rule<Iterator, CMyTag(), Skipper>              tag, text;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<CMyTag>(), Skipper> data;
};

int main() {
    testTag_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> l_gramar;
    std::string const l_test = "asd {img} {ref I}sdkflsdlk {img} wmrwerml";

    std::vector<CMyTag> l_result;
    auto f = l_test.begin(), l = l_test.end();
    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, l_gramar, qi::space, l_result);

    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Parse success: " << l_result.size() << "\n";

        for (auto& v : l_result)
            std::cout << "Name '" << v.tagName << "', Data '" << v.tagData << "'\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success: 6
Name 'text', Data 'asd '
Name 'img', Data ''
Name 'ref', Data 'I'
Name 'text', Data 'sdkflsdlk '
Name 'img', Data ''
Name 'text', Data 'wmrwerml'
```

Comment: Wow, very cool.But in this situation i misunderstand, how filled CMyTag struct, this is not obvious

Comment: Automatic attribute propagation: the fusion adaptation exposes the struct as a `fusion::vector2<string, string>` so when your parser "naturally" synthesizes a compatible attribute type (as documented [here: `tuple<A, B>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/sequence.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.sequence.attributes) assignment to the attribute referenced will be automatic.

Comment: Also this parser work unproperly for example `asd  {img} alksdla {blank} {img}s {ref S 0x5464564}s` and second text must be " alksdla ", but it have follow content "alksdla ", not space at begining

Comment: @RuslanUsifov Well, I had to make up something "reasonable" out of a very complicated grammar that didn't work! Next time, specify the expected output. Changing that is exceedingly simple: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78b0bedaa45f0072)**. It's probably ok if you spend some time learning the new things here :). Also note this is why I [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361656/r/30362395?noredirect=1#comment48827555_30361656) the other two examples. Looks like they do exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you, You post if very useful fo me, as i nube. In the first example output is as expected. So I think that Skipper and phrase_parse is not apply in this situation, and i must use qi::parse, but its very strange that space cut only from begining, I was think that in case of phrase_parse spaces will be removed from beginning and end of string(like trim does)

Comment: My answer already linked to this: ***"See also [Boost spirit skipper issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)"*** to explain the relation between skippers and `lexeme`. It explains it. Also I thought that was what you wanted, from reading the original rules (specifically your `+lit(' ')`)

Comment: For example if we want to escape { symbol, and as result doesn't recognize \{img\} as tag, how can this be implemented more effectively? Thanks

Comment: Please look at the linked samples. They do this, AFAIR.